# Extremely slow Xamarin.iOS builds

Tags: xamarin.ios

Our xamarin.iOS build is taking almost 5 minutes. Does anybody have any insight into why this is so bad? We have a number of native libraries that we're linking in. 
It wouldn't be so bad if we could do builds without cleaning but this Xamarin bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52165 means we can't do anything but clean builds.
Thanks.

```
Tasks perfomance summary:
     0.165 ms  AssignCulture                                           1 calls
     4.000 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                              4 calls
    16.440 ms  AssignTargetPath                                       18 calls
 24836.932 ms  Codesign                                                1 calls
  7561.935 ms  CodesignVerify                                          1 calls
    30.837 ms  CollectBundleResources                                  2 calls
     0.487 ms  CollectFrameworks                                       1 calls
    15.252 ms  CollectITunesArtwork                                    1 calls
    18.556 ms  CompileAppManifest                                      1 calls
    25.155 ms  CompileEntitlements                                     1 calls
    27.335 ms  CompileITunesMetadata                                   1 calls
    15.406 ms  ComputeBundleResourceOutputPaths                        1 calls
   737.619 ms  Copy                                                    8 calls
     0.689 ms  CreateAssetPackManifest                                 1 calls
     0.925 ms  CreateDebugConfiguration                                1 calls
    12.812 ms  CreateDebugSettings                                     1 calls
    87.254 ms  CreateItem                                            108 calls
     0.839 ms  CreatePkgInfo                                           1 calls
     0.193 ms  CreateProperty                                          1 calls
  2997.449 ms  Csc                                                     1 calls
     1.307 ms  Delete                                                  4 calls
     0.669 ms  DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration                         1 calls
     2.607 ms  DetectSdkLocations                                      1 calls
   138.342 ms  DetectSigningIdentity                                   1 calls
 24605.093 ms  DSymUtil                                                1 calls
    30.904 ms  EmbedMobileProvision                                    1 calls
     1.635 ms  FindAppConfigFile                                       1 calls
     1.453 ms  FindItemWithLogicalName                                 1 calls
     7.779 ms  FindUnderPath                                           1 calls
     1.678 ms  GetNativeExecutableName                                 1 calls
     0.589 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                               1 calls
     1.546 ms  MakeDir                                                 2 calls
     0.622 ms  Message                                                 2 calls
  1359.395 ms  MSBuild                                                 5 calls
272271.284 ms  MTouch                                                  1 calls
  3888.247 ms  OptimizeImage                                           1 calls
   157.087 ms  OptimizePropertyList                                    5 calls
     0.598 ms  ParseExtraMtouchArgs                                    1 calls
     0.319 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                                       1 calls
     0.989 ms  RemoveDir                                               3 calls
    46.349 ms  RemoveDuplicates                                        1 calls
    81.335 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                                1 calls
   121.745 ms  SmartCopy                                               1 calls
  6812.551 ms  SpotlightIndexer                                        1 calls
     1.953 ms  Touch                                                   2 calls
   180.862 ms  UnpackLibraryResources                                  1 calls
     2.020 ms  ValidateAppBundleTask                                   1 calls
     1.478 ms  WriteItemsToFile                                        2 calls
     4.712 ms  WriteLinesToFile                                        2 calls
```

Build succeeded.
     0 Warning(s)
     0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:05:46.1791850

Comment: which native libraries and dependencies are linked?

Comment: They're actually 3rd party .a libraries we're linking with a gcc command.

Comment: Are you building the .a libraries from source, or are you copying them precompiled during build script?  Can you omit the build of those libraries and manually copy them in during build time?

Comment: We're not building them, just copying them precompiled and linking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be done to speed up your build.

**Enable incremental builds & Enable device-specific builds**

Those are under:

```
Properties -> iOS Build
```

And will build only the parts of your code that has been changed, while the device-specific build will build only the selected device.

**Update your linker behaviour**
When building for a device you can update the Linker Behaviour to `Link all` or to `Don't link` for the simulators.
As for the incremental and device-specific builds you will find it under:

```
Properties -> iOS Build
```